# SQL for checkboxes with a many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql

I have three tables.

Directors:

```
Directors
ID 
First Name
Last Name
```

Films:

```
Films
Film ID
Title
Total
```

Directors-to-Films

```
Director-to-Films
Director ID
Film ID
```

The Directors-to-Films stores the ids like this:

```
Director ID  Film ID
1       1   
1       2
1       3
1       4
```

The films I list with checkboxes.

How do I do an SQL update so that the table looks like:

```
Director ID  Film ID
1       1   
1       3
```

(i.e. Films "2" and "4" are removed) OR

```
Director ID  Film ID
1       1   
1       2
1       3
1       4
1       5
```

(i.e. Film "5" is added to Director "1")?

Comment: "The films I list with checkboxes." - Please explain what this means? Are you referring to an HTML checkbox in a web application linked to this database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, the SQL you're looking for is just a delete and an insert:

```
delete Directors_to_Films where Director_ID = 1 and Film_ID in (2,4);

insert into Directors_to_Films (Director_ID, Film_ID) values (1,5);
```

This assumes that when you're creating the UI, that you are fetching the appropriate IDs and associating them to the controls.

---

To clarify the last statement: If I understand correctly, you're displaying the film, then a list of directors with check boxes next to their names. The user can check one or more of the boxes. if this is correct, then, presumably, you are retrieving the list of directors from the database. At the same time you should be retrieving the associated ID and storing it in a property of the check box. When it comes time to update the database, you ask the check-box control for that value to figure out which row of the database you're updating.

Comment: So...fetch the IDS using whatever language (i.e. PHP) store that in an array, compare it with the checkbox results and then decide whether that's an insert and delete?